# jenkins pipeline parallel post task to clear up docker containers

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

If I'm running parallel tasks across multiple agents, instead of having a post action on each job, how can I have it on the parallel stage itself? The issue with having them all on each stage is that *if* the stage is sharing an agent with another stage, docker system prune -f -a can interfere with the other stage.

I am trying to ensure the cache is clear on the build agent, so it's always pulling the latest fresh from Artifactory. Plus cleaning up after the build to make sure nothing is left dangling.

For example

```
stage("Docker stuff"){
    parallel{
        stage(foo){
            agent{label "docker"}
            steps{...}
        }   
        stage(bar){
            agent{label "docker"}
            steps{...}
        }   
        stage(foobar){
            agent{label "docker"}
            steps{...}
        }   
    }
    post{
        always{
            sh "docker image prune -f"
            sh "docker volume prune -f"
            sh "docker container prune -f"
            sh "docker system prune -a -f"
            sh "docker builder prune -a -f"
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with the above is that the post actions run only on the agent selected to manage the parallel stages, not the agents actually doing the running.

The issue with the below is the post actions can interfere with other stages.

```
stage("Docker stuff"){
    parallel{
        stage(foo){
            agent{label "docker"}
            steps{
                script{
                    def dockerImage = _dockerImage("docker-local/foo-image")
                    docker.withRegistry( "https://artifactory-dev.company.com/", "svc_bar") {
                        dockerImage.push()
                        dockerImage.push("latest")
                    }                  
                }
            }
            post{
                always{
                    echo "========always========"
                    sh "docker image prune -f"
                    sh "docker volume prune -f"
                    sh "docker container prune -f"
                    sh "docker system prune -a -f"
                    sh "docker builder prune -a -f"
                }
            }

        }   
        stage(bar){
            agent{label "docker"}
            steps{...}
            post{...}
        }   
        stage(foobar){
            agent{label "docker"}
            steps{...}
            post{...}
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   stage(''){
    steps {
          script {  
                    timeout(time: 24, unit: 'HOURS') {
                        try {
                           parallel(
                              a: {
                               
                              },
                              b: {
                               
                              },
                              c: {
                                
                              }
                            )
                            }catch (any){
                        //currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }finally{
              
                }
            } 
        
}      
}
}
```

post {
always {

}
}

It seems to me that you cannot perform certain actions in docker at the same time, in different nodes I do not see a problem

Comment: The issue is when you run post outside of the parallel stages, but on the host stage for the parallel section, you it doesn't run the post on each of the nodes that it used to complete the parallel tasks. And if you put the post actions inside the parallel stages themselves, it can run interfere with another task running in parallel if it hasn't yet completed.